# Is there a way to dynamically create Objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object, 2d

I have a homework problem to calculate delayed flights of different airplane carriers.  I am reading from a CSV file and have create a class for "carriers" with total flights and delayed flights.  Since there is many carriers (10 or so), how can I create carrier objects as they are read from the CSV (or a 2d array).

Instead of

```
carrier UA = new carrier("Us Airways", 100, 50);
carrier Delta = new carrier("Delta", 100, 50);
```

and hard coding all the objects.

right now the CSV data is in a 2D array, and the non object oriented code is as follows.

```
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("delayed.csv"));
    String [] nextLine;

    String[][] flightData = new String[221][3];
    int i=0;    
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

            for(int r = 0; r<2; r++){
            flightData[i][0] = nextLine[1];
            flightData[i][1] = nextLine[6];
            flightData[i][2] = nextLine[7];
            }
        i++;
        //System.out.println("Carrier: " + nextLine[1] + "\t\tTotal: " + nextLine[6] + "\t\tDelayed: " + nextLine[7] + "");
        }
        while(flightData != null){
        carrier 
        }
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Carrier> listCarrier = new ArrayList<Carrier>();      

while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

    listCarrier.add(new Carrier(nextLine[1], Integer.valueOf(nextLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(nextLine[7])));

}
```

Note that the class Carrier should start with an uppercase.

If you want to avoid dupplicates, you can use HashMap instade of ArrayList as follows:

```
Map<String, Carrier> listCarrier = new HashMap<String, Carrier>();
```

In order to insert a new record, use:

```
Carrier carrier = new Carrier(nextLine[1], Integer.valueOf(nextLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(nextLine[7]));
listCarrier .put(nextLine[1],carrier );
//Here the key is the carrier name, and the value is the carrier object
```

If you have dupplicate carriers with same name but different values, only the last one will be kept in the HashMap.

To get a carrier from the list, use:

```
listCarrier.get("carrier_name")
```

And this would return the carrier with name "carrier_name" from the Map, if available.

Comment: +1 although I'd verify that the carrier only appears once with in the file, but the concept is valid

Comment: It wasn't a prerequisite in his question, but he can use a hasmap for that, i guess. Thanks for the +1.

Comment: I agree, but you might just want to clarify it ... posters are awesome and leaving details out ;)

Comment: the carriers do appear more than once in the file. I just didn't mention it for some reason.  That is a slick piece of code. But since MadProgrammer and you brought it up, how would you use a hashmap?

Comment: I think I just wanted to focus on the basics of dynamically creating objects and thats what was frustrating me

Comment: Yeah this is great.  Thanks for helping me.  Definitely dove into new materially- and I like it. I'll have to read up a bit, but thanks again.

Comment: Although, the hash would skip creating a new carrier, but the flight info is valuable.  I was just going to add the data via setters and modify the carrier object by say... delayedflights = delayedFlights+additionalFlights. But my data was originally coming from a 2d array so it seemed more intuitive to me. Can hashmaps do this?

Comment: @user1093111 Yup looks good :D.  Without more information, it's difficult to know how the OP is going to update existing carrier information, but the basics are there, shame I can't give you another up-vote :P

Comment: @user1093111 the OP is the Original Poster, and that would be you :) and for you question, hashmap and arraylist will only "hold" your objects, you will need to set the attributes yourself after you get the objects from the list

Comment: hahaa that's what I thought, but hey, you never know with all this jargon